# How to copy even values into an array and display them?

Tags: c++, arrays

so I am having a bit of a problem, but I don't know if it's my code or my compiler that's creating the issue. My assignment is to ask the user to input integers, while the program stores the even numbers in one array and the odds in another array. When the user enters in 0, the program is supposed to show them how many evens they put in and how many odds, and then list the values in each array.

So I wrote up a program for it quickly and I thought it would work just fine. No such luck. It always got the number of evens and the number of odds correct, but instead of listing the numbers from the arrays, it usually lists the last x numbers the user input (x being equal to the number of elements in that array). I also occasionally get wacky 5+ digit integers appearing at the end of the output.

Now, the thing is, my code doesn't look like it has anything wrong in it, so I am thinking it may be my compiler that's creating the problem.

So here is my code, anyways:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int input, remainder, even = 0, odd = 0;
    int evenArray[even];
    int oddArray[odd];
    cout << "This program accepts integers until you enter 0.\nPlease enter a value: ";
    cin >> input;
    while (input != 0) {
        remainder = input % 2;
        if (remainder == 0) {
            evenArray[even] = input;
            even++;
        }
        else {
            oddArray[odd] = input;
            odd++;
        }
        cout << "Enter another integer: ";
        cin >> input;
    }
    cout << "\nThe number of evens is " << even << ".\n";
    cout << "The even values are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < even; i++) {
        cout << evenArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "The number of odds is " << odd << ".\n";
    cout << "The odd values are: ";
    for(int i = 0; i < odd; i++) {
        cout << oddArray[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

And here's an example of it being run:

```
This program accepts integers until you enter 0.
Please enter a value: 1
Enter another integer: 2
Enter another integer: 3
Enter another integer: 4
Enter another integer: 5
Enter another integer: 5
Enter another integer: 3
Enter another integer: 2
Enter another integer: 4
Enter another integer: 6
Enter another integer: 4
Enter another integer: 3
Enter another integer: 0

The number of evens is 6.
The even values are: 2 4 2 4 6 3 
The number of odds is 6.
The odd values are: 2 4 2 4 1912356720 32767
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could tell me what  is the problem here.

Comment: Hint: What does `int evenArray[even];` do when you have initialized `even` to `0`?

Comment: "Now, the thing is, my code doesn't look like it has anything wrong with it, so I am thinking it may be my compiler." That's not the case, it wouldn't compile.

Comment: 1) `int evenArray[even];` No variable length arrays in C++, 2) Even if variable length arrays were allowed, `even` is `0`. Btw this is c++, use `std::vector` or `std::array` if you already know the size.

Comment: Your code doesn't look like it has anything wrong with it????   You're using variable length arrays, which are invalid in C++ (although, admittedly, some C++ compilers support them as an extension for compatibility with C).    Even worse, the way you are using variable length arrays is incorrect in C as well - and will give undefined behaviour.    You need to read up on how to work with arrays in C++.   Or learn to use standard containers, like vectors.

Answer (score 2):

For starters variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature and moreover you may not declare an array with the number of elements equal to 0 like this

```
int input, remainder, even = 0, odd = 0;
int evenArray[even];
int oddArray[odd];
```

and such a declaration does not make sense.

If the size of an array is unknown at the compile time then use standard container `std::vector`.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    std::vector<int> evenArray, oddArray;
    int input;

    cout << "This program accepts integers until you enter 0.\nPlease enter a value: ";

    while ( cin >> input and input != 0 ) 
    {
        if ( input % 2 == 0) 
        {
            evenArray.push_back( input );
        }
        else 
        {
            oddArray.push_back( input );
        }

        cout << "Enter another integer: ";
    }

    cout << "\nThe number of evens is " << evenArray.size() << ".\n";
    cout << "The even values are: ";
    for ( int x : evenArray ) 
    {
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The number of odds is " << oddArray.size() << ".\n";
    cout << "The odd values are: ";
    for ( int x : oddArray ) 
    {
        cout << x << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Another approach is to declare arrays of some fixed maximum size and to restrict the user to enter no more elements than the given maximum. For example

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    const size_t N = 100;

    int evenArray[N], oddArray[N];
    size_t even = 0, odd = 0;

    cout << "This program accepts integers until you enter 0.\nPlease enter a value: ";

    int input;

    while ( even < N and odd < N and cin >> input and input != 0 )
    {
        if ( input % 2 == 0) 
        {
            evenArray[even++] = input;
        }
        else 
        {
            oddArray[odd++] = input;
        }

        cout << "Enter another integer: ";
    }

    cout << "\nThe number of evens is " << even << ".\n";
    cout << "The even values are: ";
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < even; i++ ) 
    {
        cout << evenArray[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    cout << "The number of odds is " << odd << ".\n";
    cout << "The odd values are: ";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < odd; i++)
    {
        cout << oddArray[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't learned vectors yet. so I don't understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder how you got that to compile...

Anyway, use `std::vector` as "dynamic array", because you don't know how many numbers the user will input.

Another thing is that you can speed up parity checks by using binary operator `&`. You simply and your number with 1 like that `someNumber & 1`. If the result is 1, then the number is odd.

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> even, odd;
    int userDecision;
    while(cin >> userDecision && userDecision) {
        int input;
        cin >> input;
        if((input & 1) == 1) {
            odd.push_back(input);
        } else {
            even.push_back(input);
        }
    }

    cout << "Number of evens " << even.size() << endl;
    // Print even numbers
    cout << "Number of odds " << odd.size() << endl;
    // Print odd numbers

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check whether your reading of input failed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues:

1) `int evenArray[even];` Generally, C++ does NOT support variable length arrays. Some compilers do but you should never do this.

2) Even if 1) wasn't true, you initialize `even` and `odd` with a size of `0`.

So, like I said this is C++, you should always try to use `std::vector` or `std::array` if the size is already known. Here's how your program should look:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

   std::vector<int> even, odd;
   int input;

   std::cout << "This program accepts integers until you enter 0.\nPlease enter a value: ";
   while (std::cin >> input && input != 0)
       (input % 2 == 0) ? even.push_back(input) : odd.push_back(input);

   std::cout << "\nThe number of evens is " << even.size() << ".\n";
   std::cout << "The even values are: ";
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < even.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << even[i] << " ";

   std::cout << std::endl << "The number of odds is " << odd.size() << ".\n";
   std::cout << "The odd values are: ";
   for(unsigned i = 0; i < odd.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << odd[i] << " ";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to add a check whether your reading of input failed or not.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that you didn't show him that issue.